# How to call Ajaxdecorator or javascript in onSubmit method of AjaxLink (Wicket)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

```
public class engageLink extends AjaxLink{
    private Engage engage;
    private String name;

    engageLink(String string, Engage anEngage,String name) {
        super(string);
        this.engage = anEngage;
        this.name = name;
        hasEngage=((Application) getApplication()).getVtb().hasEngagement(engage,name);
        if(hasEngage)
            this.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model("alert('This is my JS script');"), ";"));
    }
    boolean randevuAlmis;


    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

         if(hasEngage){
              //do nothing or call ajax on failure script
         } else{
                 ((Application) getApplication()).getVtb().addEngagement(engage, name);
         }
         setResponsePage(new Sick(name));
    }
        @Override
            protected org.apache.wicket.ajax.IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator()
            {
                return new AjaxCallDecorator()
                {
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence decorateOnSuccessScript(CharSequence script)
                    {
                        return "alert('Success');";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence decorateOnFailureScript(CharSequence script)
                    {
                        return "alert('Failure');";
                    }



                };
            };
}
```

This is my code.IN the method on click i call ajax onfailure script .but it doesn't work.

I tried adding javascript in the constructor.It does not work too.

What is the problem.

Note i call ajaxdecorator like;

```
getAjaxCallDecorator().decorateOnFailureScript("some message");
```

How can i solve these problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to call the failure script without a failure? If that's the case, you could call:

```
target.appendJavascript("alert('Failure');");
```

or

```
target.appendJavascript(getAjaxCallDecorator().decorateOnFailureScript("some message"));
```

BUT, you are calling setResponsePage() at the end of the onClick() method, I think that could block any scripts from being executed, since you are redirecting to another page instead of simply executing the ajax response.

Comment: thank you guy firstly they dont work.Later i moved setResponsePage line into the else statement.Result is so good.Thank you very much